# how make if select value is equal to div id function dynamic?

Tags: jquery, filter, equals

try to make a dynamic class filter that checks the value of a dropdown (select option value) and the div id. If they are equal show only the divs with equals value and div.

my code now is down here but doesn't work. The problem is the $(".mix").id(); ) I believe

```
    <script>
    $('select').change(function(){

      if($("select").val() == 'everything' ){ 
        $('.mix').show();
      }
      $( ".container>.mix").each(function(){

          if($("select").val() == $(".mix").id(); ){ 
            $('.mix').hide();
            $(".mix").id().show();
          }

      });

     });
</script>
```

Comment: Give some more code(HTML code). Your mix is mixing our thoughts.

Comment: All elements have the mix class for the show everything method only divs with à certain id must be filterd with the equal function http://tomesen.testout.nl/referenties/

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 $(".mix").id();
```

to

```
$(".mix").attr("id");


if($("select").val() == $(".mix").attr("id")){ 
            $('.mix').hide();
            $(".mix").attr("id").show();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm...the example below is working with one ID, but not with the above code...see: http://tomesen.testout.nl/referenties/

```
$('#filter').change(function () {
            if ($('#filter option:selected').text() == "Alle referenties"){
                    $( ".mix" ).show( "slow");
            }
            else if ($('#filter option:selected').text() == "CA"){
                    $( ".mix" ).hide();
                    $( "#CA" ).show( "slow" );
            }        
        });
```